# How to increase size of ggplot - squeezed horizontal bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some values against US states in a horizontal bar chart in GGPlot.

The code is:

```
g <- df %>% 
  select(Sample.Measurement, State.Name) %>% 
  group_by(State.Name) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  ggplot(., mapping = aes(x=reorder(State.Name, n), y =n))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.8, position = position_dodge(width = .25))+
  labs(
    title = "",
    y= "Frequency"
  )+
  coord_flip()

g+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"))
```

The theming element was in a bid to change the text size.

What I really want to do is extend the depth of the chart so that the individual states have more space. How do I do that?

[image: GGplot chart]

Comment: Increase the size of the plot. If you are exporting it as an image or in rmarkdown, increase height. If you are in RStudio, drag the plot window to make the window bigger..

Comment: It's an R Studio notebook. I can't see anywhere to drag it. How do I change height? Sorry, I'm very inexperienced with R.

Comment: Please include this piece of information in your original post, it's very important.

Comment: Just adding for the search engines, How to increase size of ggplot in an R Notebook.

Comment: Actually, I know this is a really old question, but whould it be possible for you to change the title to "How to increase size of ggplot in R Notebook - squeezed horizontal bar chart"? I've been looking for this answer for AGES and that might help others to find it more quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the chunk options, namely `fig.height` and `fig.width`.

e.g.

````
```{r fig.height = 10, fig.width = 5}
#your plot code
```
````